# It suits me more OR It suits me better

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

When speaking about features of character, which form is correct?

- smiling suits her more
- being a bit drunk suits him better

Comment: Both are equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible though
[the *better* version is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suits+_NOUN_+better%2Csuits+_NOUN_+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

The results for the various individual pronouns, *me/her/him*, are also consistent with the overall one:

[Ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suits+me+better%2Csuits+me+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[Ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suits+her+better%2Csuits+her+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[Ngram3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suits+him+better%2Csuits+him+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)